Maximum likelihood on Ticket Collector
There are $N$ types of tickets. A ticket is drawn, noted, and kept back. Any ticket may be observed equally likely on a given draw, regardless of what happened in the previous draws. $n=519$ tickets have been drawn so far, among which $m=315$ distinct tickets were observed. What $N$ maximises the probability that for a given $n$, $m$ takes the provided value? A solution which doesn't take advantage of the computationally tractable size of the given numbers would be appreciated. Both exact formulae and approximate but fast formulae are appreciated.
Just ran into the question in the context of a video game, which has news titles running up top, and it records how many I have seen, and how many of those were distinct.
As for approaching the problem, I'm actually clueless. I see that there are $N^n$ different sequences of draws that could have happened. Writing down an expression for when there are exactly $m$ different coupons drawn seems hard, though. So I tried to write an expression for at most $m$ tickets. To do so, I decided I want to fix $m$ of the $N$ tickets which are allowed to occur. But of course, cases where we have less than $m$ tickets will fall under multiple categories, so I cannot just take a sum over all possible $m$ things to occur, as that overcounts. I don't think that the expression that comes from writing an inclusion-exclusion here is particularly revelatory, or computationally nice.

[1] What do you mean by the $;$ provided $;;$ value ? [2] Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

The probability of seeing $m$ unique observations in a sample sized $n$ taken with replacement from a population sized $N$ where each is equally likely to be drawn is $$\frac{S_2(n,m)\,  N! }{(N-m)!\,N^n   }$$
where the $S_2(n,m)$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.
Since $S_2(n,m)$ does not depend on $N$, we can say the likelihood is proportional to $\frac{N! }{(N-m)! \,N^n  }$ and seek to maximise that. We could say we want the largest $N$ for which $\frac{N!}{(N-m)!\,N^n} \ge \frac{(N-1)!}{(N-1-m)!\,(N-1)^n}$, i.e.  $$\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n \ge \frac{N-m}{N}.$$
In your example of $n = 519, m = 315$, this suggests $\hat N = 471$ (the likelihood for $472$ is only very slightly lower). Equality in the final expression comes when $N\approx 471.995$ and we then round down to an integer for $\hat N$.
You might think about approximating with $\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n \approx e^{-n/N}$ and then trying to solve $e^{-n/N} = \frac{N-m}{N}$ for $N$ to get about $\dfrac{n}{\frac nm + W\left(-\frac nm e^{-n/m}\right)}$ using the Lambert W function. With $n = 519, m = 315$ this suggests equality with $N\approx 472.6$, which is close but very slightly too high.
A method of moments estimate for $N$ would be essentially be the same, though without the rounding down: the expected number of unique elements seen is $N\left( 1- \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^n\right)$ and finding the $N$ which makes this equal to $m$ is the same as solving $\left(1-\frac1N\right)^n = \frac{N-m}{N}.$
